# How to do the selection effect similar to the people or email app of windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ListView in a BasicPage template (code below) and I want to add an effect similar to the people or email app of Windows 8.1 (image below) to distinguish selected item from the rest of items. And I need to open a popup when an item is selected in such a way. How is that possible?

[image]

```
<Page
    x:Class="IslamicCenter.BasicPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:IslamicCenter"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page title" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
            <ListView SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- My item template goes here -->
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You're looking for context menus, there's a few guides on how to get started with them such as http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/19/windows-phone-toolkit-context-menu-getting-selected-item-within-a-long-list-selector.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in the Mail and many other apps is called a context menu. In Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT apps, there's an easy way to get the context menu by using Flyouts - MenuFlyout to be exact. There's a [code sample on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Flyout-and-MenuFlyout-78629692) on how to use the Flyouts.

In your case, the easiest thing to do is to extend your ListView.ItemTemplate like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="pin to start" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="edit" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

            // rest of your ItemTemplate

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And then react on Holding or Tap event like this:

```
FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
```

[I wrote a blog post about all of this](http://igrali.com/2014/04/29/show-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1/), and also about a way to show a context menu using MVVM approach.